# Binding RadGridView with stored procedure's result in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, radgridview

I have stored the result of a stored procedure (in Entity Framework) in an `IList` and then bind my grid with this `IList`. When this result is null the grid hasn't got any columns but I need to show these columns in the grid. Is there any way to solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
IList list = new ArrayList();

try
{
    var context = new SabzNegar01Entities1();

    list = (from p in context.tbl_ReturnSalesFactor_D
            let add = (p.MainNum * p.Fee)
            let pureAdd = ((p.MainNum * p.Fee) - (p.MainNum * p.Discount)) + ((p.Tax + p.Charges) * p.MainNum)
            let taxChange = (p.Tax + p.Charges) * p.MainNum
            let discount = p.Discount * p.MainNum
            where p.DocNo == inDocNo
            select new { p.Row, p.StockCode,  p.tbl_Stock.PDescription, p.Fee, p.MainNum, add, taxChange, discount, pureAdd }).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    PMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error in Reading  ReturnSalesFactor_Details Data");
}
```

and binding:

```
radGridView_Product.DataSource = list ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

- define a C# class that matches the data that you're getting back from the stored procedure (e.g. `SalesInfo` or whatever you want to call it)
- then define your `IList` to be a `List<SalesInfo>` (**please** don't use the crappy old `ArrayList` anymore!)
- when you call the stored procedure, but you get no values back, you just add a dummy `SalesInfo` entry to your list being returned, that e.g. has `no data found` as its description and everything else is empty/0.0

That way, your method will always return at least one element, and since that element is there, the gridview know it's columns and what to call them

**Update:**

I would **first** define a class to hold all those properties you want to display in your gridview:

```
// just a data container to hold the information - call it whatever you like!
// also: with the datatypes, I am just *GUESSING* because you didn't exactly tell us
// what those values are - adapt as needed !
public class SalesInfo
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Fee { get; set; }
    public decimal MainNum { get; set; }
    public decimal Add { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxChange { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal PureAdd { get; set; }
}
```

Next, define a method that goes and gets that data from the stored procedure - if not data is returned, add a dummy entry instead:

```
// Define a method to return an IList of that data container class defined above
public IList<SalesInfo> GetSalesInfo()
{
    // please, as of .NET 2.0 - use the List<T> and stop using ArrayList!
    IList<SalesInfo> list = new List<SalesInfo>();

    try
    {
        // put your context usage into using()..... blocks to ensure proper disposal
        using (var context = new SabzNegar01Entities1())
        {
             // fetch the data, turn it into SalesInfo records
             list = (from p in context.tbl_ReturnSalesFactor_D
                     where p.DocNo == inDocNo
                     select new SalesInfo
                            {
                                Row = p.Row,
                                StockCode = p.StockCode,
                                Description = p.tbl_Stock.PDescription,
                                Fee = p.Fee,
                                MainNum = p.MainNum,
                                Add = p.MainNum*p.Fee,
                                PureAdd = ((p.MainNum*p.Fee) - (p.MainNum*p.Discount)) + ((p.Tax + p.Charges)*p.MainNum),
                                Discount = p.Discount*p.MainNum,
                                TaxChange = (p.Tax + p.Charges)*p.MainNum
                            }).ToList();
        }

        // if you get back no data -> add a dummy entry
        if (list.Count <= 0)
        {
             list.Add(new SalesInfo { Description = "(no data found)" });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error in Reading  ReturnSalesFactor_Details Data");
    }

    // return the resulting list
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I have to use foreach for adding SalseInfo to this List?I have done it before but my boss wanted me to change it because of this loop.could you give me an example please?

Comment: There is another problem:This solution has got several projects:Info,IInfo,Business,IBusiness and UI(IInfo and IBusiness are interface and their implementations are in Info and Business ).In UI project I can see only interface projects ,so in IBusiness project it have to be like this:IList<ISalesInfo> GetSalesInfo(); how can I store the result of this query on IList<ISalesInfo>(interface of SalesInfo)?